# Find element yielding the largest value w.r.t. custom function

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

I made a function to find the element that yields the largest value when put into a custom functor.

I think this is missing from the STL. I can think of three ways to do this in STL:

- Transform the container by the functor. Find the maximum in the transformed version. Take the corresponding element from the original container.
- Transform the container to an iterable of `std::pair`s containing the iterators to the original values and the corresponding functor result value. Write a custom comparison function which compares the `.second` of the pairs. Find max among the pairs with `std::max_element`. Take `.first` of the resulting iterator.
- Use a custom comparator functor in `std::max_element` (`return f(lhs) < f(rhs)`).

The first two are really cumbersome and the third calls the functor twice as many times as necessary. Hence this:

```
template<typename Iterable, typename UnaryFun>
auto maxElementBy(Iterable const& iterable, UnaryFun criterion)
    -> decltype(std::begin(iterable))
{
    typedef decltype(criterion(*std::begin(iterable))) CriterionResult;

    auto itCurrent = std::begin(iterable);
    auto itEnd = std::end(iterable);

    if (itCurrent == itEnd)
    {
        return itEnd;
    }

    CriterionResult bestValue = criterion(*itCurrent);
    auto itBest = itCurrent;
    ++itCurrent;

    for (; itCurrent != itEnd; ++itCurrent)
    {
        CriterionResult currentValue = criterion(*itCurrent);
        if (bestValue < currentValue)
        {
            itBest = itCurrent;
            bestValue = std::move(currentValue);
        }
    }
    return itBest;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: While the standard does not offer applying functors before comparing it allows to specify a custom comparator. This makes it easy to implement a custom comparator that takes a functor and applies it before comparing objects.

Comment: @Nobody In that way the functor will be called twice as many times as necessary.

Comment: If the operation is too costly you could offer a caching comparator that caches the last two results and reuses them if appropriate. The "beauty" of the comparator approach is, that you could also use it with other functions (like `std::sort`)

Comment: std::accumulate with a simple custom function achieves the same result.

Comment: @vnp Do you mean accumulating with std::pair<Iterator, double>? Remember that I need an iterator as a result, not just the function value. I tried it and it seems to be horribly unreadable. Using algorithms has no benefit if the resulting code is more error-prone and unmaintainable than the usual loop with `(current > best)` checks.

Comment: Actually, `std::pair<CriterionResult, Iterator>`, (for `std::max` to work). The code I tried looks quite OK, but of course everything is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: I'm not very comfortable with the `decltype`. This might yield a reference, and you need something local assignable for `bestValue`. I'd use `auto bestValue = criterion(*itCurrent);` instead. For `currentValue`, you can use `auto&& currentValue = ..;` because that doesn't need to be assignable. However, if it returns a reference, you might have an unintended side-effect via the move.

Comment: @vnp Now I tried the `std::accumulate` version again but the problem is that the binaryOp that must be supplied to `std::accumulate` will get the next *dereferenced* iterator (not the iterator itself), so we cannot propagate `itBest` with this method. How did you imagine it?

Answer (score 2):

Setting aside the std::accumulate discussion, I have one recommendation. The signature

```
template<typename Iterator, typename UnaryFun>
auto maxElementBy(Iterator first, Iterator last, UnaryFun criterion)
    -> Iterator
```

seems to be more flexible. It allows partial ranges, and seems more in line with the std design approach.

Comment: You are right, that is the STL style. I don't really like it, though. It's really cumbersome to write (and read) `maxElementBy(std::begin(someNamedVector), std::end(someNamedVector), fun)` compared to `maxElementBy(someNamedVector, fun)`. Hopefully ranges will be introduced to C++ sometime.